# Python/Kivy 2.1.0: how to access body of URL request

Tags: python, request, kivy, urlrequest

Hope you all doing fine.
I am new here and hopefully you might help me. Developing my first Python mobile app right now and using Kivy 2.1.0 for this. Unfortunately I am blocked in Kivy which seems to be too easy in pure Python development.

**My goal:**
accessing the body of an URL HTTP request so that I can work with the resulting string of that body. I want to compary if the string contains "STATE=ON" or "STATE=OFF"

**response of my desination URL gives back:**
*ControlSTATE=ON*
(or optional STATE=OFF, depending on the current WIfi Switch status)

**the solution in Python (without Kivy):**

```
import requests
   x = requests.get('URLofYourChoise)   
   print(x.text)
```

And this works (tested!)

**the solution in Kivy should look sth. like this:**

```
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
   body = UrlRequest(' URLofYourChoise  ')
   print(body.text)
```

And this does not work :(

But what can I do with "body"? Where is the content from the HTTP response?

While watching in debug modus on my variable body, I can find the desired response in:
body → _queue → 0 → 2:

> [Debug inspected variable 'status'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByYJq.jpg)

I read the Kivy documentation, but honestly I think I have a lack of knowledge somewhere.

Hopefully you are able to solve my problem :) Thank you in advance!

I tried to read the [Kivy URLrequest documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html) in order to understand the available properties

I tried to use the Python **request** library → not possible as the application builder (GitHub → Repository → Actions) throws an error because of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UrlRequest](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html) uses an async method. You have to define callback function to be called when response will be retrieved. Here you have same code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Application(App):

    def build(self):
        root_layout = BoxLayout()
        label = TextInput()
        root_layout.ids['content'] = label
        root_layout.add_widget(label)
        return root_layout

    def request_callback(self, req, result):
        print(f'HttpStatus: {req.resp_status}')
        print(f'Response Headers: {req.resp_headers}')
        print(f'Response: {result}')

        self.root.ids.content.text += f'HttpStatus: {req.resp_status}\n\n'
        self.root.ids.content.text += f'Response Headers: {req.resp_headers}\n\n'
        self.root.ids.content.text += f'Response: {result}\n'
        self.root.ids.content.cursor = 0, 0

    def on_start(self):
        UrlRequest('http://neverssl.com', self.request_callback, debug=True)

Application().run()
```

If you want to use it in synchronous way you may use `wait` method like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class Application(App):

    def build(self):
        root_layout = BoxLayout()
        label = TextInput()
        root_layout.ids['content'] = label
        root_layout.add_widget(label)
        return root_layout

    def on_start(self):
        req = UrlRequest('http://neverssl.com', debug=True)
        req.wait()

        print(f'HttpStatus: {req.resp_status}')
        print(f'Response Headers: {req.resp_headers}\n\n')
        print(f'Response: {req.result}\n')

        self.root.ids.content.text += f'HttpStatus: {req.resp_status}\n\n'
        self.root.ids.content.text += f'Response Headers: {req.resp_headers}\n\n'
        self.root.ids.content.text += f'Response: {req.result}\n'

Application().run()
```

Comment: When I use UrlRequest always I take HttpStatus: 301, If I use "requests.get" everything is OK.